# Solr - OverlappingFileLockException when concurrent commits

Tags: java, indexing, lucene, full-text-search, solr

I'm using solr version 1.4.0 with tomcat 6. I've 2 solr instances running as 2 different web apps with separate data folders. My application requires frequent commits from multiple clients. I've noticed that when more than one client try to commit at the same time, these OverlappingFileLockException start to appear. Can anything be done to rectify this problem? Please find the error log below. Thanks

---

HTTP Status 500 - null

java.nio.channels.OverlappingFileLockException
    at sun.nio.ch.FileChannelImpl$SharedFileLockTable.checkList(FileChannelImpl.java:1215)
    at sun.nio.ch.FileChannelImpl$SharedFileLockTable.add(FileChannelImpl.java:1117)
    at sun.nio.ch.FileChannelImpl.tryLock(FileChannelImpl.java:923)
    at java.nio.channels.FileChannel.tryLock(FileChannel.java:978)
    at org.apache.lucene.store.NativeFSLock.obtain(NativeFSLockFactory.java:233)
    at org.apache.lucene.store.Lock.obtain(Lock.java:73)
    at org.apache.lucene.index.IndexWriter.init(IndexWriter.java:1550)
    at org.apache.lucene.index.IndexWriter.<init>(IndexWriter.java:1407)
    at org.apache.solr.update.SolrIndexWriter.<init>(SolrIndexWriter.java:190)
    at org.apache.solr.update.UpdateHandler.createMainIndexWriter(UpdateHandler.java:98)
    at org.apache.solr.update.DirectUpdateHandler2.openWriter(DirectUpdateHandler2.java:173)
    at org.apache.solr.update.DirectUpdateHandler2.addDoc(DirectUpdateHandler2.java:220)
    at org.apache.solr.update.processor.RunUpdateProcessor.processAdd(RunUpdateProcessorFactory.java:61)
    at org.apache.solr.handler.XMLLoader.processUpdate(XMLLoader.java:139)
    at org.apache.solr.handler.XMLLoader.load(XMLLoader.java:69)
    at org.apache.solr.handler.ContentStreamHandlerBase.handleRequestBody(ContentStreamHandlerBase.java:54)
    at org.apache.solr.handler.RequestHandlerBase.handleRequest(RequestHandlerBase.java:131)
    at org.apache.solr.core.SolrCore.execute(SolrCore.java:1317)
    at org.apache.solr.servlet.SolrDispatchFilter.execute(SolrDispatchFilter.java:338)
    at org.apache.solr.servlet.SolrDispatchFilter.doFilter(SolrDispatchFilter.java:241)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:233)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:191)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:127)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:298)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:859)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:588)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:489)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:636)

**type** Status report

**message** null

java.nio.channels.OverlappingFileLockException
    at sun.nio.ch.FileChannelImpl$SharedFileLockTable.checkList(FileChannelImpl.java:1215)
    at sun.nio.ch.FileChannelImpl$SharedFileLockTable.add(FileChannelImpl.java:1117)
    at sun.nio.ch.FileChannelImpl.tryLock(FileChannelImpl.java:923)
    at java.nio.channels.FileChannel.tryLock(FileChannel.java:978)
    at org.apache.lucene.store.NativeFSLock.obtain(NativeFSLockFactory.java:233)
    at org.apache.lucene.store.Lock.obtain(Lock.java:73)
    at org.apache.lucene.index.IndexWriter.init(IndexWriter.java:1550)
    at org.apache.lucene.index.IndexWriter.<init>(IndexWriter.java:1407)
    at org.apache.solr.update.SolrIndexWriter.<init>(SolrIndexWriter.java:190)
    at org.apache.solr.update.UpdateHandler.createMainIndexWriter(UpdateHandler.java:98)
    at org.apache.solr.update.DirectUpdateHandler2.openWriter(DirectUpdateHandler2.java:173)
    at org.apache.solr.update.DirectUpdateHandler2.addDoc(DirectUpdateHandler2.java:220)
    at org.apache.solr.update.processor.RunUpdateProcessor.processAdd(RunUpdateProcessorFactory.java:61)
    at org.apache.solr.handler.XMLLoader.processUpdate(XMLLoader.java:139)
    at org.apache.solr.handler.XMLLoader.load(XMLLoader.java:69)
    at org.apache.solr.handler.ContentStreamHandlerBase.handleRequestBody(ContentStreamHandlerBase.java:54)
    at org.apache.solr.handler.RequestHandlerBase.handleRequest(RequestHandlerBase.java:131)
    at org.apache.solr.core.SolrCore.execute(SolrCore.java:1317)
    at org.apache.solr.servlet.SolrDispatchFilter.execute(SolrDispatchFilter.java:338)
    at org.apache.solr.servlet.SolrDispatchFilter.doFilter(SolrDispatchFilter.java:241)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:233)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:191)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:127)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:298)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:859)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:588)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:489)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:636)

**description** The server encountered an internal error (null

java.nio.channels.OverlappingFileLockException
    at sun.nio.ch.FileChannelImpl$SharedFileLockTable.checkList(FileChannelImpl.java:1215)
    at sun.nio.ch.FileChannelImpl$SharedFileLockTable.add(FileChannelImpl.java:1117)
    at sun.nio.ch.FileChannelImpl.tryLock(FileChannelImpl.java:923)
    at java.nio.channels.FileChannel.tryLock(FileChannel.java:978)
    at org.apache.lucene.store.NativeFSLock.obtain(NativeFSLockFactory.java:233)
    at org.apache.lucene.store.Lock.obtain(Lock.java:73)
    at org.apache.lucene.index.IndexWriter.init(IndexWriter.java:1550)
    at org.apache.lucene.index.IndexWriter.<init>(IndexWriter.java:1407)
    at org.apache.solr.update.SolrIndexWriter.<init>(SolrIndexWriter.java:190)
    at org.apache.solr.update.UpdateHandler.createMainIndexWriter(UpdateHandler.java:98)
    at org.apache.solr.update.DirectUpdateHandler2.openWriter(DirectUpdateHandler2.java:173)
    at org.apache.solr.update.DirectUpdateHandler2.addDoc(DirectUpdateHandler2.java:220)
    at org.apache.solr.update.processor.RunUpdateProcessor.processAdd(RunUpdateProcessorFactory.java:61)
    at org.apache.solr.handler.XMLLoader.processUpdate(XMLLoader.java:139)
    at org.apache.solr.handler.XMLLoader.load(XMLLoader.java:69)
    at org.apache.solr.handler.ContentStreamHandlerBase.handleRequestBody(ContentStreamHandlerBase.java:54)
    at org.apache.solr.handler.RequestHandlerBase.handleRequest(RequestHandlerBase.java:131)
    at org.apache.solr.core.SolrCore.execute(SolrCore.java:1317)
    at org.apache.solr.servlet.SolrDispatchFilter.execute(SolrDispatchFilter.java:338)
    at org.apache.solr.servlet.SolrDispatchFilter.doFilter(SolrDispatchFilter.java:241)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:233)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:191)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:127)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:298)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:859)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:588)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:489)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:636)
) that prevented it from fulfilling this request.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you're doing multiple concurrent commits. Don't do that. Instead, switch to autoCommit (either by [configuration](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/SolrConfigXml#Update_Handler_Section) or by using add with [commitWithin parameter](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/UpdateXmlMessages#Optional_attributes_for_.22add.22)). That way, Solr will figure out the actual commits for you.